# Mounting an Amazon EC2 instance on MAC OS X

Tags: amazon-ec2, storage

What are some methods for transferring files to and from Amazon EC2 instances. I'm looking for solutions / tools for editing files as well as copying files to EC2 instances from both Mac and Windows.

For example, what are some solutions for mounting a drive from an instance locally?

Generally, what other methods are out there?

Comment: You'd probably get a better response on superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

If the EC2 instance is running, you can use the usual set of tools you'd use for a non-virtual instance (e.g. scp using WinSCP if it's a *nix machine from a Windows desktop).

Answer (score 0):

caelyx is correct, provided your EC2 instance has SSH setup on it.  Depending on what you're doing, you may want to look at Elastic Block Storage (EBS) -- your EBS storage can be treated like any other block-level device so you can mount it like you would a hdd from your Mac, another server, etc.

http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/